# How long are flutter versions supported

Tags: flutter

In popular frameworks like Angular, React, .Net,... it is clear which version of the frameworks is supported for how long. How long are flutter versions supported? I can only find an article which states compatibility between versions, not how long a version is supported by the team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the primary support is always "upgrade to the latest".  So far, there have been no critical security errors that required additional patches in older breaking-changes versions.  That's not to say that this couldn't happen, but "migrate forward" seems like the best way to keep being supported.

Also, this is a community project, so you can always hire third-party support for any combination of packages or releases that you want.  You are not dependent on "the vendor" for that, because "the vendor" is effectively *all of us*.

Comment: Nice answer, and well explained